# How to query an array of objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to query an array of objects "sortedData", where each object has two values (ItemId, Sort), for a specific ItemId and set the 'Sort' value. Like this below but this isn't the correct linq syntax.

```
var sortedData = db.Fetch<object>("SELECT ItemId, Sort FROM CollectionItems WHERE CollectionId = @0", collectionId);
dataWithSort = db.Fetch<OrganizationForExportWithSort>(TpShared.DAL.StoredProcedures.GetOrganizationsForTargetListUI(clientId, organizationIdList));
foreach(OrganizationForExportWithSort export in dataWithSort)
            {
                    export.Sort = sortedData.Select("Sort").Where(sortedData.ItemId == export.Id);
            }
```

Comment: Whenever you use Linq, you're going to receive a data collection in return.
The Where statement allows you to refine what elements are in the resulting collection, and Select allows you to perform an operation on each element. I highly recommend you do some simple tutorials in Linq before attempting this.

Comment: I also tried export.Sort = from d in sortedData
                                      where d.ItemId == export.Id
                                      select d.Sort; But this didn't work either because it doesn't find d.ItemId

Comment: The code sample you provide won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want the Sort property from the item that matches that particular ID. This being the case, you have a few problems with what you've written:

- "Where" and "Select" both take Lambda expressions, not property names and expressions, so the code snippet you provide shouldn't compile.
- "Where" and "Select" both return collections (even if there's only one item that actually matches the "Where" filter; in fact, even if *no* items in the collection match the condition in the "Where" clause it'll still return a collection, albeit an empty one). Think of LINQ Select more in terms of running a transform on a collection and LINQ "Where" as applying a filter to one.
- As a general rule for LINQ queries, if possible, you should actually run "where" before "select" (filter first, then apply some kind of transform to the remaining items).
- In this case, I think you actually just want one item, so you can actually use "FirstOrDefault" instead of "Where." This will leave you with a single .NET object. This is analogous to the TOP 1 restriction in SQL. Once you have the .NET object you can retrieve the property from the object itself.

Try this:

```
foreach(OrganizationForExportWithSort export in dataWithSort)
        {
                export.Sort = sortedData.FirstOrDefault(data => data.ItemId == export.Id)?.Sort;
        }
```

The "?" is a new C# feature that will try to call .Sort on the object if (and only if) the query succeeded in finding an item with that ID. If it doesn't it'll just return null.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Linq sorting?

```
var sortedData = db.Fetch<object>("SELECT ItemId, Sort FROM CollectionItems WHERE CollectionId = @0", collectionId);
dataWithSort = db.Fetch<OrganizationForExportWithSort>(TpShared.DAL.StoredProcedures.GetOrganizationsForTargetListUI(clientId, organizationIdList));

// create a list ordered by fields
var sorted = dataWithSort.OrderBy(o => o.SomeField).ThenBy(o => o.OtherField);
```

The o in the lambda stands for object...

I will add my voice to the chorus of folks saying to read up on some good linq tutorials. [Start Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)